# how to build a Cakefile to run node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

Currently making my way through "[Teach Yourself Node.js in 24 Hours](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672335956)", and I was hoping to do as much of the code as possible in CoffeeScript rather than JavaScript.

Have `coffee-script` and `node` both installed.

I'm still new to the cake development system -- could somebody point me in the direction of how to put together a `Cakefile` to load a simple server, like `server.coffee` in order to run demo code?

Comment: Imho it would be way easier to translate an existing example into CoffeScript and launch it via `coffee server.coffee`, so you don't have to learn many things at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any part of [Node's API](http://nodejs.org/api/) in a Cakefile, including [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) for executing commands.

With [`child_process.spawn()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), you should be able to use:

```
task 'server', 'Start up the server', (options) ->
  spawn = require('child_process').spawn
  child = spawn 'coffee', [ "#{__dirname}/server" ]

  child.on 'error', console.error
  child.on 'exit', -> console.log('exit')
```

Comment: great this is a good start, though I'm just getting an exit when I try to run `cake server`

Comment: @fox If it exits immediately without error, it's may mean it isn't yet listening for communication.

Comment: I actually had it directed to the wrong file, all is well now